# Stop scrollingY and start animating marginLeft when trying to continue scrolling down, when finish marginLeft continue scrollingY

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

I need to disable scrolling when arriving to #container using CSS and jQuery. After, each time we try to scroll down #div2 goes marginLeft -100px. When we arrive to -300px we should be showing HS4 and we could continue scrolling down
Anybody knows how to do it?